# I want to deploy a logic app standard tier with workflow using arm template in ci/cd

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app deployed in consumption plan using terraform.
Now I want to deploy a logic app standard tier with the workflow using arm template and create a ci/cd pipeline for it.

Comment: Have you tried to deploy a logic app using arm template? Do you get an error?

Comment: This is a statement, not a question.

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps to be followed in order to create a logic app workflow using arm template & release pipeline.

1. Upload your ARM template file to your repro or git hub & copy the link.
2. Create a release pipeline, with an empty job & add a task ARM template deployment as shown below

[image]

3. Select the deployment scope as `resource group`, in the Azure Resource manager Connection click on authorize to configure an Azure service connection. A new Azure service principal will be created and added to the Contributor role, having access to all resources in the selected subscription.
4. In the template location, select the option `URL of the file` & pass the URL of the `ARM template`

   [image]
5. Pass the required fields based on your requirement, click on Save & click on Create Release (this will deploy the arm template resources in the select subscription).